# How do I print out words from a .txt word list?

Tags: c++

I have a .txt word list file with 3000 english words that I want to be printed out.

Here's what I've done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

vector<string> wordList(){

    string path = "file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/BnS/words.txt";
    ifstream file(path);
    vector<string> list;
    string oneWord;
    while (file >> oneWord){
        list.push_back(oneWord);
    }
    return list;
}

void testWordList(){

    vector<string> words = wordList();
       
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++){
        cout << words[i] << endl;
    }
}

int main(){    
    testWordList();
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously something is wrong since I dont get anything when i run it. What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Make sure that `path` is the correct path to the file.

Comment: check the output of `file.is_open()`

Comment: I just dragged the file from my folder onto google chrome and copied the adress. That works right?

Comment: can you try changing  `string path` to `string path = "C:/Users/me/Documents/BnS/words.txt";`, also check in that location word.txt is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::ifstream` usually doesn't support reading from URL.

The line

```
    string path = "file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/BnS/words.txt";
```

should be

```
    string path = "C:/Users/me/Documents/BnS/words.txt";
```

If this doesn't work, try this:

```
    string path = "C:\\Users\\me\\Documents\\BnS\\words.txt";
```

(`\` is used as escape sequence, so you have to write `\\` to express `\`)

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhhh... Removing file:/// worked!! Thanks!